# How to manually query from the database using symfony2 and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to query the database in my user repository like this (symfony2):

```
namespace Doobin\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function pageAccess($User=1,$Page='_home')
{
    $query="SELECT `user` FROM `vu001_user_permission` WHERE `user` = '$User' AND `path`='$Page'";
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

But it won't work.
It stop working when it arives at the live
`$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();`

I copied that from the symfony website tuturial.

I Also tried this too:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT `user` FROM `vu001_user_permission` WHERE `user` = '$User' AND `path`='$Page'");
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

It stop working when it arive to line `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`

And tried this too:

```
namespace Doobin\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function pageAccess($User=1,$Page='_home')
{
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM UserBundle:User p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
}
```

`$this->getEntityManager()` now working, please help I'm so confiused.
I checked everything.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kind of looks like you are mixing symfony 1 and 2.

In symfony2 you would most likely use the NativeQuery methods to achieve this. (see here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Answer (score 7):

Do the following to get connection:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$conn = $em->getConnection();
```

To Query,

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```